# Adding @objc(NewClassName) breaks Storyboard references in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if anyone else had run into this problem;

I need to add the line @objc(NewClassName) to my View Controller so that it can be seen by its Objective-C counterparts with an Objective-C prefixed class name.

```
import UIKit

@objc(NewClassName)

class ClassName: UIViewController {
```

- View Controller code is written in Swift
- Storyboard references work fine without the @objc line
- Adding the @objc line gives the error:

  ```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x17f62f70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainView.'
  ```

*Note: mainView is a View I have added myself. This error does not crop up without the @objc*

Removing the @objc line makes it all work as intended.

This is how it is set up in the Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard setup]

Comment: Where did you add @objc and can you show how your storyboard looks like ? The outlets and the class and module area ?

Comment: I have added the code and a screenshot to the original question, I hope this helps.

Comment: What does the `mainView` property look like?

Comment: "mainView" is just a simple UIView. I only reference it to add a cornerRadius and clipsToBounds = true, which I could probably both do in the Storyboard, though I would prefer to do it the original way for consistency throughout the app.

Comment: Is `mainView` marked as an IBOutlet?

Comment: @Caleb it is indeed

`@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!`

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the storyboard class name to `NewClassName`. The runtime doesn't find `ClassName` and instantiates a generic `UIViewController`, causing the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however doing this, the Storyboard can no longer see the code automatically in the "Automatic" section. Getting to it manually does not allow you to link the items up either.

Comment: Then you have to decide which of the behaviours you prefer :)

Comment: Haha I was afraid you would say that ;) but I think you're right in that regard.